# PHP static function outside of a class

Tags: php

I came across this code snippet in the symfony docs

```php
// config/packages/workflow.php
use Symfony\Config\FrameworkConfig;

return static function (FrameworkConfig $framework) {
    // code...
}
```

I'm curious about the use of the `static` keyword to declare a function at the top level of a file (outside of a class)

FYI, I do understand its use in the context of a class, so that's not what I'm asking

Similar questions have mentioned its use in C/C++ to do with linkage, so I wonder if its related to that

Someone please clarify. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a ["static anonymous function"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#functions.anonymous-functions.static).

Normally, when you create an anonymous function (closure), it holds a reference to the current value of `$this`, so that you can write code like this:

```
class Example {
    public function makeClosure() {
        // Create an anonymous function
        $myClosure = function() {
            // Inside the closure, access $this
            $this->doSomething();
        };
        return $myClosure;
    }
    public function doSomething() {
        echo 'hello';
    }
}

// Create an object, and a closure referencing it
$example = new Example;
$closure = $example->makeClosure();

// Unset the object, but keep the closure around
unset($example);

// Run the closure
$closure();
```

Sometimes, this is useful - in this example, we want to run `doSomething()` on the object, so need `$this`. But sometimes, it causes problems - it prevents the object being "cleaned up", which might waste memory or other resources.

In that case, you can add the `static` keyword to the anonymous function declaration, and `$this` won't be available inside that closure.

Comment: Aha, I see. So this is specific to anonymous functions?

Comment: @TheMonarch Yep, the "function" and "static" keywords are just being reused for a different (but related) purpose.